# Why don't I have "Create a basic sample project" in HardHat?

Tags: nodejs, hardhat, smart-contract-wallets, polygon

The situation is like this. I watched the tutorial and it came to "Deploy Smart Contract". I create a folder and open it in Visual studio. I activate the command "npm i -D hardhat" (as in the instructions) and the author has a folder "node-modules" (in the upper left corner) and some inscriptions. Next, I activate "npc hardhat" and in the tutorial there is a choice "Create a basic sample project", etc., and I have "Create a JavaScript project", etc., but there is no "Create a basic sample project".
Where did I do wrong? Thank you in advance for your understanding and help:3

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ne33FSVnMzw
Timecode: 39:07

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes projects used in tutorials get updates making the tutorial somewhat obsolity, and that is the cae here. You didnt do anything wrong but if you check their [official documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#overview) the `Create simple project` option doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: And now there is no HardHat version with "Create a basic sample project" anywhere else?

Comment: You can choose the typescript or js projects, both are just a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

So hardhat updated their docs on March 4th 2023, creating a basic sample project seems to work again if you follow the steps here.
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/project-setup

Comment: All chads use Foundry

Comment: @RyanSea good option too